# unable to redirect after facebook login using web

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, facebook-login

I am trying to implement facebook login in my facebook 
here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>

  function statusChangeCallback(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      window.location = "welcome.html";

     } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                 FB.login();

                 } else {
                         FB.login();
                        }
     }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
  });


  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
          alert("authlogin subscription");
          window.location = "welcome.html";
      });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="checkLoginState();">FB Login</a>    
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to redirect to welcome.html after successfull login, where as if I click login button as already logged in user am able to redirect to welcome.html.
i am unable to find the reason for redirection after FB.Login().

Comment: Same problem here. Did you able to get any answer by chance.
If yes, plz do post as Answer.